# How to read this vector: visitors array from clicky.com

Tags: php, arrays

I have this vector format:

```
<response status="ok">
   <type type="visitors">
        <date date="2015-06-27">
            <item>
                <value>40</value>
            </item>
        </date>
        <date date="2015-06-28">
            <item>
                <value>41</value>
            </item>
        </date>
   </type>
</response>
```

What I want to do, is to read the vector by dates, like this:

> 2015-06-27 > 40 visitors
>   2015-06-28 > 41 visitors
>   ...

I was unable to read the date, all I get shown is:

> Array, Array ...

Comment: what did you tried? show us your code

Comment: I have tried all possible ways. This is the last version, that still doesn't display the code anywhere:

foreach( $data as $item ) {
 echo ("$data[0] .. <br>");
    echo ("1) ".$data ." > ".$item["date"]."<br>");
 foreach( $item as $date ) {
  echo ("$item[0] .. <br>");
  echo ("2) ".$item["date"] ." > ".$date["date"]."<br>");
    
        foreach( $date as $value ) {
            echo ("$date[0] .. <br>");
   echo ("$value[0] .. <br>");
      echo ("3) ".$date ." > ".$value."<br>");
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `simplexml_load_file`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Assuming you have your XML in a file called visitors.xml, you can use the following:

```
<?php

$visitors = simplexml_load_file("visitors.xml");
foreach($visitors->type->date as $date) {
    echo ($date['date']) . " > " . $date->item->value . " visitors\n";

}
```

or you can use `simplexml_load_string` if you have your XML in a string.

Comment: clicky.com offers XML parsing as well, maybe that version would me more friendly, I'll try it out, thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you very much, axxis! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I was unaware of that, I did accepted now, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Its not an XML file, is a PHP response from clicky.com server, obtained like this:

```
$data = unserialize( file_get_contents("http://api.clicky.com/api/stats/4?site_id=$site_id&sitekey=$site_key&type=visitors&output=php"));
```

and then, var_dump ($data);

its a vector, in the format shown in my first post.

I used all sorts of parsing, this is the last one:

```
foreach( $data as $item ) {
echo ("$data[0] .. <br>");
echo ("1) ".$data ." > ".$item["date"]."<br>");
foreach( $item as $date ) {
    echo ("$item[0] .. <br>");
    echo ("2) ".$item["date"] ." > ".$date["date"]."<br>");

    foreach( $date as $value ) {
        echo ("$date[0] .. <br>");
        echo ("$value[0] .. <br>");
        echo ("3) ".$date ." > ".$value."<br>");
    }
}
```

}

Still, the date isnt showing up anywhere, only arrays or nothing..